# Splitting a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string in C# the following way:

Incoming string is in the form

```
string str = "[message details in here][another message here]/n/n[anothermessage here]"
```

And I am trying to split it into an array of strings in the form

```
string[0] = "[message details in here]"
string[1] = "[another message here]"
string[2] = "[anothermessage here]"
```

I was trying to do it in a way such as this

```
string[] split =  Regex.Split(str, @"\[[^[]+\]");
```

But it does not work correctly this way, I am just getting an empty array or strings

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `But it does not work correctly this way` - Please be specific. What do you mean by that? does it throw an exception? does it not produce the expected result? If so, what does it produce? can you post that? Please ask your question properly, otherwise you'll get downvotes and close votes quickly here.

Comment: use the one of the Split() method overloads on the string class.

Comment: Replace all linefeeds with empty strings, then split on "][".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: That is a good idea, however if the messages themselves can contain line breaks, it would remove them also.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `Regex.Matches` method instead:

```
string[] result =
  Regex.Matches(str, @"\[.*?\]").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: no need Cast<Match>

Answer (score 18):

The [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx) method returns sub strings *between* the instances of the pattern specified. For example:

```
var items = Regex.Split("this is a test", @"\s");
```

Results in the array `[ "this", "is", "a", "test" ]`.

The solution is to use [`Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) instead.

```
var matches =  Regex.Matches(str, @"\[[^[]+\]");
```

You can then use Linq to easily get an array of matched values:

```
var split = matches.Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Value)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Did you test your `Split` example? Aside from not properly escaping the `\w`, the result you mention is completely wrong.

Comment: @KennethK Thanks. I wrote that edit on my way out the door, and didn't have a chance to proofread it. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use lookaround assertions for your splitting.

e.g.

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=\])(?=\[)");
```

This approach effectively splits on the void between a closing and opening square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex you could use the `Split` method on the string like so

```
Split(new[] { '\n', '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

You'll loose `[` and `]` around your results with this method but it's not hard to add them back in as needed.

Comment: That will also break on `\n` between `[` and `]`. I don't think that's what OP wants