# return string based on wildcard in c#

Tags: c#, wildcard

I have tried to find a method in c# to return a string of a wildcard match, however I can only find information on how to return if it contains the wildcard match, not the string the wildcard match represents.

For example,

```
var myString = "abcde werrty qweert";
var newStr = MyMatchFunction("a*e", myString);
//myString = "abcde"
```

How would I create `MyMatchFunction`?  I have searched around on stackoverflow, but everything that has to do with c# and wildcard is just returning boolean values on if the string contains the wildcard string, and not the string it represents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421651/splitting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching strings with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299671/matching-strings-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using Regex?

For instance, with the pattern `a.*?e`, you could achieve this effect

```
string sample  = "abcde werrty qweert";
string pattern = "a.*?e";
Regex rgx      = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(sample);

foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Which would print out

```
abcde
```

Comment: It does not match for input `"ae"`! Use `"a.*?e"` instead of `"a.+?e"`!

Answer (score 0):

Default of wildcard search for `"abcde werrty qweert"` with pattern of `"a*b"` will returns `"abcde werrty qwee"`, but you can use gready search for the result of `"abcde"`.

Function for `WildCard` match using `Regex`:

```
public static string WildCardMatch(string wildcardPattern, string input, bool Greedy = false)
{
    string regexPattern = wildcardPattern.Replace("?", ".").Replace("*", Greedy ? ".*?" : ".*");
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, regexPattern, 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return m.Success ? m.Value : String.Empty;
}
```

Result:

```
var myString = "abcde werrty qweert";

var newStr = WildCardMatch("a*e", myString);
//newStr = "abcde werrty qwee"

newStr = WildCardMatch("a*e", myString, Greedy: true);
//newStr = "abcde"
```