# Extract unspecified characters from string

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to figure out how to extract unspecified characters from string.

For example: I have long string `"1.1.1 sadsajkdn 1.1.2.1 dfkjskf 2.1.1"` and so on. What I'm trying to do is to split the string after each number. I've followed previous tutorial to use string.split('1'), but I would need to extract the entire number part which can be different. Can I specifi something like `string.split('*.*.*')` where star represents any number from 1-9?

Thanks

Comment: I'll write up an answer in a moment. As an aside, there's nothing specific to ASP.NET or MVC about this. I'd suggest removing those tags - certainly my answer will just be a console application. If you believe there *is* something ASP.NET-specific about the question, it would be worth explaining that within the question itself.

Comment: Look at regularexprsions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421651/splitting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using [*regular expressions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions). I believe you want:

- At least one digit
- As many occurrences as necessary of "a dot followed by at least one digit"

That's represented by the regex of

```
\d+(\.\d+)*
```

- `\d` means "a digit"
- `+` means "at least one"
- `\.` means "a dot" (just `.` would mean "any character")
- `*` means "zero or more"
- The bracketing is to group the "dot followed by at least one digit"

Here's a complete example showing this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> pieces = SplitToDottedNumbers("1.1.1 sadsajkdn 1.1.2.1 dfkjskf 2.1.1");
        foreach (string piece in pieces)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(piece);
        }
    }

    static List<string> SplitToDottedNumbers(string text)
    {
        // Inline for readability. You could create this just once.
        var regex = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)*");
        // LINQ-based implementation
        return regex.Matches(text)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(match => match.Value)
            .ToList();

        /* Alternative implementation
        var pieces = new List<string>();
        var match = regex.Match(text);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            pieces.Add(match.Value);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        return pieces;
        */
    }
}
```

(There may be a simpler way of extracting all values. You could call `Matches`

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what I was searching form. Thank you