# PigLatin how can I strip punctuation from a string? And Then add it back?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

Working on program for class call pig Latin. It works for what I need for class. It ask just to type in a phase to convert.  But I notice if I type a sentence with punctuation at the end it will mess up the last word translation. Trying to figure out the best way to fix this. New at programming but I would need away for it to check last character in word to check for punctuations. Remove it before translation and then add it back. Not sure how to do that. Been reading about char.IsPunctuation. Plus not sure what part of my code I would had for that check.

```
public static string MakePigLatin(string str)
    {
        string[] words = str.Split(' ');
        str = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].Length <= 1) continue;
            string pigTrans = new String(words[i].ToCharArray());
            pigTrans = pigTrans.Substring(1, pigTrans.Length - 1) + pigTrans.Substring(0, 1) + "ay ";
            str += pigTrans;
        }
        return str.Trim();
    }
```

Comment: I thought about just first reading each char and strip out punctuation at the end and then adding it back to the end. But that would not work if I have more then one sentence.

Comment: This is just for extra credit since we did not have time to go over this chapter. For extra credit only need to type in phase and have it translate which code above does that. I was just playing around with it and seen problem it I did 2 sentences. I was splitting words up separating by space.  str.Split(' ') but there would not be a space between last word and punctuations.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you strings of letters for converting while passing through any non-letter characters that follow them.

Splitter based on [Splitting a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421651/splitting-a-string-in-c-sharp)

```
public static string MakePigLatin(string str) {
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"([a-zA-Z]*)([^a-zA-Z]*)");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.Length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; ++i) {
        string pigTrans = matches[i].Groups[1].Captures[0].Value ?? string.Empty;
        if (pigTrans.Length > 1) {
            pigTrans = pigTrans.Substring(1) + pigTrans.Substring(0, 1) + "ay";
        }
        result.Append(pigTrans).Append(matches[i].Groups[2].Captures[0].Value);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

The matches variable should contain all the match collections of 2 groups.  The first group will be 0 or more letters to translate followed by a second group of 0 or more non-letters to pass through. The StringBuilder should be more memory efficient than concatenating System.String values.  I gave it a starting allocation of double the initial string size just to avoid having to double the allocated space.  If memory is tight, maybe 1.25 or 1.5 instead of 2 would be better, but you'd probably have to convert it back to int after. I took the length calculation off your Substring call because leaving it out grabs everything to the end of the string already.

Comment: Not following how the code works or how to uses it. reading about Regex now. Watching some video on Regex would I need to add usging System.Text.RegularExpressions; to use it?

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions; got rid of red line under Match[]. But still trying to figure problem for Regex.Matches with red line. Been changing Matches to words, pigTrans but still red line.

Comment: I get error with this line of code:  Match[] matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"([a-zA-Z]*)([^a-zA-Z]*)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]' ClassLibrary

Comment: I removed all the cast and select stuff from the other answer and stuck with a basic MatchCollection to iterate through.  I tested the answer in DotNetCore 2.1 and it worked.  It doesn't handle shifting capital letters around though, so the first word in a sentence is going to look odd, but the punctuation stays put.  This specific function should only require using statements for System, System.Text, and System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Comment: I'm learning here so Regex.Matches(str, @"([a-zA-Z]*)([^a-zA-Z]*)"); The first group is ([a-zA-Z]*) which looks for letters and the second group has ^ which I take to mean does not have letters.  I was playing around with TakeWhile(char.IsPunctuation))  and TakeWhile(x => !char.IsPunctuation(x))); But now I will play around with your code and try to learn everything its doing.

Comment: I did letters vs not letters so any numbers, spaces, carriage returns, etc. would pass through without being converted to pig latin.